# Silverlight app in iframe access to parent window

Tags: html, silverlight, dom, iframe

I have Silverlight application test page named A.html hosted in an iframe which is an element of B.html, so is there a way for Silverlight app to access elements in B.html by referring something like HtmlPage.Document..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can always walk up the DOM tree by doing something like this:

```
var htmlElement = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentElement.Parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the container html page, add following function:

```
function GetParent
{
   return parent;
}
```

In the SL control, do this:

```
HtmlWindow parent = (HtmlWindow)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("GetParentWindow");
```

Now to invoke any function from the parent Html page, just call

```
parent.Invoke("myFunction");
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Ahmad.

Answer (score -4):

Using Silverlight/Moonlight is very risky. Most of your website's guests will not have this plugin installed. This will strongly limit your website accessibility.

Use Flash instead, or even better use only [x]html+css+javascript.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer. It's akin to telling someone to use Linux or Mac OS X when they say they've got a problem with a Windows virus.